# How to execute another promise in finally?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have a promise chain and I need to write to a file using `fs.writeFile` after the chain is executed. As far as I can see, `finally` accepts a Promise as a return type:

```
finally(onfinally?: (() => void) | undefined | null): Promise<T>
```

But looking at my code, `eslint` doesn't seem to like it:

### My Code:

```
    return this.downloadProject(data)
      .finally(() => {
        return fse.writeFile('', 'foo');
      })
```

### VSCode:

[image]

Is this caused by a misconfiguration of my Eslint or is this a code smell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ECMAScript specification has for [`finally`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/control-abstraction-objects.html#sec-promise.prototype.finally), in step 6:

> i. Let *result* be ? Call(*onFinally*, **undefined**).
> ii. Let *promise* be ? PromiseResolve(*C*, *result*).
> ...etc

So there is a use for the value returned. If this return value happens to be a promise, then the promise returned by `finally` will be locked into the promise returned by its callback. However, the resolution value will still be that of the original promise.

This can be seen in the following test script:

```js
Promise.resolve(3)
       .finally(() => new Promise(resolve => 
            setTimeout(() => resolve(5), 2000))
        )
       .then((value) => console.log("resolved to", value));

// Message appears after 2 seconds, and value is 3
```

And similarly, when the original promise is rejected, the promise returned in the `finally` callback is awaited, but the rejection remains:

```js
Promise.reject(3)
       .finally(() => new Promise(resolve => 
            setTimeout(() => resolve(5), 2000))
        )
       .catch((value) => console.log("rejected with", value));

// Message appears after 2 seconds, and value is 3
```

There is a clearly a consequence to returning a promise in the `finally` callback, so we *could* argue that the linter should not complain about it.

### Ignoring a rejection

If you want to work around this linter warning, or if you really want to have the effect of a `then`, so that it returns a new promise *with its own outcome*, than weave a `.catch` just before a `.then`:

```
return this.downloadProject(data)
      .catch(() => {})  // This promise will fulfill after a rejection
      .then(() => {
        return fse.writeFile('', 'foo');
      })
```

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The `.finally` returns a promise, in order to allow promise-chaining. However, the function inside should not return anything, hence the `() => void | undefined`.

Comment: Is the only workaround to move the write call inside the “then” block?

Comment: You can do an `finally` with an empty function `() => {}` following a `then`

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative solution

```js
function wait1sec() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(()=>resolve(1), 1000)
  });
}

wait1sec()
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    return wait1sec()
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  })
  .finally(() => {
    console.log(2)
    return wait1sec()
  })
  .finally(() => {
    console.log(3);
    return wait1sec()
  })
  .finally(() => {
    console.log(4);
  })
  .finally(() => {
    console.log(5);
  })
```